# Use FetchedResultsController to render TypeA object from a Table of TypeB using their many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I know there are *similar* questions on SO, but none of them worked for me.

I'm writing my first iOS app (a simple bookstore application) whose model consists of a Book table and a User table. They have a many-to-many relationship called "purchasedBook".

```
Book <--purchasedBooks--> User
```

I'm using a fetchedResultsController to render these books in a TableView.

But I can't figure out how to render " all books in the purchasedBook set in the User database". i.e. how can I tell the fetchedresultscontroller to iterate over the Book* objects which are present as a set in User.purchsedBooks ?

Basically, I want to be able to do the following in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell* cell;
cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bookPlace" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Get the book for this indexPath
Book* book = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = book.title;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = book.subtitle;

return cell;
}
```

This is my attempt:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL purchasedBooks"];
request.sortDescriptors = @[];
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                   managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                                     sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                              cacheName:nil];
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are coming at it from the wrong direction. You should be fetching `PurchasedBook` entities who have a user equal to the user you are referencing and then get the associated book.

Note that I am treating `PurchasedBook` as if it is a proper entity of its own instead of just a hidden join table.  You can add additional metadata in the `PurchasedBook` entity such as date purchased, price etc.

The creation of the `NSFetchedResultsController` would be:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"PurchasedBook"];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"user == %@", [self currentUser]]];
[self setFetchedResultsController:[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

BTW, entities should always be singular in name, not plural. Note the change in this code.

With this FetchedResultsController, your cell construction changes just a bit:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell;
    //this should be using a static for the identifier. Magic strings are risky
    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bookPlace" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //You should make sure your cell is not nil just in case your magic string has a typo
    if (!cell) {
        //build it by hand here
    }

    // Get the book for this indexPath
    PurchasedBook* purchasedBook = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Book *book = [purchasedBook book];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[book title]];
    [[cell detailedTextLabel] setText:[book subtitle]];

    return cell;
}
```

It helps to stop thinking about Core Data objects as tables.  Core Data is not a database.  It is your object model that happens to be able to persist to a database.  Persistence is a secondary function of Core Data, not the primary.  Once you reverse that perspective in your head these types of things become easier to resolve.

### Update

> But wouldn't it be more efficient to be able to access the books through the user (a user will probably have 100 or so books) rather than compare books (to users) from the Book (table?) which will probably have 50,000 objects?

No because you are wanting to look at Books not Users.  If you were displaying a list of Users then you would fetch users. This is about getting the data that you want to display which is Books.

> The relationship between Book and User is described as "many-to-many" in the question. In that case, the predicate probably should be "ANY users == %@".

Which is correct as Martin pointed out.  However I skipped a step.  In a situation like this, you will invariably discover that you want more information about the relationship between a user and a book (year purchased, quality of book, price paid, etc) and end up putting a *meta* object between the User and Book.  I added it out of habit and experience in my answer as I suspect you will end up adding it eventually anyway :)

Comment: The relationship between Book and User is described as "many-to-many" in the question. In that case, the predicate probably should be `"ANY users == %@"` .

Comment: Ah ! I understood. This works for me. But wouldn't it be more efficient to be able to access the books through the user (a user will probably have 100 or so books) rather than compare books (to users) from the Book (table?) which will probably have 50,000 objects ? Doesn't really matter in my case, but just curious.

Comment: As Martin said, ANY users rather than user ==.